# System device output volume is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I have interface element that display current system volume in my app. During volume changes when user in app i can monitor and set it using following:

```
[RACObserve([AVAudioSession sharedInstance], outputVolume) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber* x) {
        self.knobControl.position = -([x floatValue] * 4.65) + 1e-7;
    }];
```

However, when my application become inactive and  then become active again i tried to use following logic to set that element to current active system volume (that is changes while app was in background):

```
/* Notifications */

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didBecomeActive)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];


-(void)didBecomeActive{

    /* Call it to set correct value after application become active from background */

    CGFloat outputVol = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
    self.knobControl.position = -(outputVol * 4.65) + 1e-7;
}
```

However, when i set volume to max in app and then press home button, then set system volume, for example, to 2/16 of max, then when i enter app [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume] is still show me that volume is set to max (old value).

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, however I would suggest checking that the method 'didBecomeActive' is actually being called. Technically it should work, and I think that might be the issue. Honestly when things don't work I always suggest you do some simple debugging and also share these with us, so we have the insights and can better help you. So if you could check wether the method is being called and what the outputVolume value is in that call using an NSLog.